# LinkedEntityId referring to custom object record id

Tags: custom-object, contentdocument, contentdocumentlink

Is it possible to map ContentDocumentLink (LinkedEntityId field) to a custom object record? As per the doc [Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.object_reference.meta/object_reference/sforce_api_objects_contentdocumentlink.htm) for LinkedEntityId, it has not been mentioned to be possible to reference a custom object, but I can see many standard objects. If it is not possible: Do we have any alternative solution to map a ContentDocument to a custom object in Salesforce?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you can relate documents to custom objects. Here's the code I used to determine that:

```
for(sobjecttype relatedTo: ContentDocumentLink.LinkedEntityId.getDescribe().getReferenceTo()) {
    if(relatedTo.getDescribe().isCustom()) {
        System.debug(relatedTo);
    }
}
```

You should see your custom objects listed in the debug logs.

Answer (score 4):

The documentation does mention (though a little off-handedly) that custom objects can be set for `LinkedEntityId`, emphasis mine.

> #### Description
>
> ID of the linked object. Can include Chatter users, groups, records (any that support Chatter feed tracking **including custom objects**), and Salesforce CRM Content libraries.

There are also several other mentions of "custom object" in the information for the "Visibility" field, which would be an odd thing to include if `ContentDocumentLink` couldn't link to custom SObjects.